# Upload large database SQL file

Tags: mysql, ssh, ftp

I've a database of more than 20Gb of size on my hard disk. What is the best way to upload it with the least (money) load possible on the server? 
- I'm on Windows 7. 
- I have FTP and SSH access on the server.

I avoid using FTP because my connection cuts off a lot, I can't imagine I re-upload again the file after failing on 99%.

I found some tools that split the large .sql file to small .sql files, but they didn't mention how to gather these files again into one file.

Another way is to archive the big .sql file to .rar with -v option, upload them through FTP then unpack them. But unpacking will also cost, right?

I know it will cost in any cases, but any best practice will be strongly appreciated.

Comment: What exactly is costing you here?  Are you paying a high price for bandwidth or CPU?  If bandwidth is your concern, then I would look at RSYNC over SSH with compression.

Comment: My concerns are Bandwidth and upload time. My internet connection cuts a lot. Zipping a .sql file into small .zip files won't effect the data of the database?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uploading through SFTP (WinSCP is a free graphical utility) would allow you to resume and does have the option to enable compression built in.

If you want to save bandwidth/temporary storage costs you could gzip the archive before uploading it and then use a command similar to gunzip yourdatabase.sql.gz | mysql -u  -p .  I believe both izarc and 7zip are capable of creating a .gz file.

Comment: Thanks Jared, your answer is very helpful, I'll figure out the WinSCP and go ahead.

Comment: I doubt it, but if this is a shared server you may wish to speak to the administrator of it.  Depending on the exact database structure, importing a 20GB .sql file may take a few hours, maxing out the cpu and/or hard drive the entire time.  If I remember correctly, pulling in a 2GB database took me about 30 minutes on a quad core machine with SAN storage.

Comment: Structure is not complex. I'll give up the time factor, I can wait.

Comment: I just settle for resuming after losing connection and having the least pressure on the server.

Comment: I suggest using a screen session either way (if it is available on your server).  That way if you get disconnected there is not a risk of the command getting terminated.

Comment: That is important. I'll ask the server owner about that.

Answer (score 0):

Share it on a secure http server, and download it on the other side using a Download manager that has bandwidth limitation and Resume support. i would recommend to use Internet Download manager or Free download manager for this purpose.

I use the same method to share large file over WAN.

(Make sure you share it on secure http server, where the access is password protected and based on IP restriction)

You can use this small HTTP server for sharing this file over http: http://www.aprelium.com/abyssws/

Comment: As I mentioned, my connection cuts a lot. That will probably prevent the sharing process, right?

Comment: even if it does, still it can be reduced, thats the beauty of HTTP protocol. its Resume support

Comment: What do you think Frank about zipping the big .sql file into small chunks? Is that safe for my data when I extract them on the server?

Comment: zipping would be time consuming, and unzip process would be very resource intensive on the server. the method i gave you will put least level of load on server. as Zip/Unzip require a lot of computing resources. and for 20GB,it would be tough for server (as you are saying you dont want to put much load on it)

Comment: Zip or gzip will result in a massive reduction in the size of most SQL files because most of the time they are pure text.  Importing a 20GB SQL file which may grow to be even bigger due to indexes is going to put a huge amount of load on any server anyway.  The question is just whether you would prefer to save bandwidth/time or cpu/memory.

Comment: What if I prefer cpu/memory?

Comment: Just for a general idea on one site I administer.  Their database backup (compressed with bzip2) is 334MB, the SQL file is 1.5GB, and, before innodb compression, the database itself takes over 2GB of space on disk. 4.47 million rows.  It took around 20-30 minutes to import that database and around 3 minutes to extract the sql file.

Comment: @Devy: Dont forget to Vote the answer :)

Comment: If you prefer cpu/memory just upload the raw .sql file.  Compressing it may reduce the size to around 4-5GB but it will cause the extraction time to take slightly longer.

Comment: I logged in. Now I cant vote :). Well I'm not Devy anymore, I'm Nadjib :) .